# Django form submits, but won't save to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, mysql-python

I'm using a ModelForm, but not using Django's auth system.  I am also trying to set a random password, but have commented out that bit because I'm not sure if it is causing issues.

Currently, the following will return 'success', but will not save to the database.

```
def registration(request):
if request.POST:
    data = request.POST.copy()
    data['date_joined'] = datetime.date.today()
    data['last_login'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    form = UserForm(data)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['username'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            #ran_pw = User.objects.make_random_password(length=12)
            #user.set_password(ran_pw)
            user = User()
            user.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.m_init = form.cleaned_data['m_init']
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.institution = form.cleaned_data['institution']
            user.department = form.cleaned_data['department']
            user.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(form.errors)
else:
    form = UserForm()
    return HttpResponse(form.non_field_errors)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably this happens when the user already exists in the database. That's because you only actually set the data when the user doesn't exist. Move all the field setting code back one indentation level.

Actually, you shouldn't set the fields manually at all - the whole point of using a ModelForm is that you do `form = UserForm(data, instance=user)` and then if the form is valid you just do `form.save()`.

Comment: This is a suggestion I'd found elsewhere.  The idea was that it checks if the username exists, then only saves the registration form if it doesn't.  I'm testing it with random, unique names, so not sure why it's behaving as if the user already exists.  It works if I skip checking if the username exists.

Comment: So just to be sure, put a print in and see what user it gets